# Create a popup widget with a native shadow

Tags: qwidget, qt6

I'm on KDE Plasma 6.0.2 + Wayland. I need to create a widget that inherits from `QWidget` with the `Qt::Popup` window flag set and has a natural shadow (i.e., the shadow is drawn by the window manager). Actually, I could inherit my widget from `QMenu` (which inherits from `QWidget` with the `Qt::Popup` window flag set), but there are a lot of methods I don't need. The problem is that my custom widget (which, once again, is inherited from `QWidget` with the `Qt::Popup` window flag set) doesn't have a natural shadow, while `QMenu` does. And I can't understand why, because they are essentially two similar classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. In Plasma 6, the presence of a shadow under the popup widget depends on the current style. For the Breeze style (which is default for Plasma 6), you need to add a dynamic property `_KDE_NET_WM_FORCE_SHADOW` and set it to `true`:

```cpp
class CustomPopup : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CustomPopup(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QWidget(parent, Qt::Popup)
    {
        setProperty("_KDE_NET_WM_FORCE_SHADOW", true);
    }
};
```

See [here](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/breeze/-/blob/08ee525469d169eb169ecefbaab90b3564b6126f/kstyle/breezeshadowhelper.cpp#L288) for details.